# Proving a relation is a total order relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, relations

Consider question #21 part a:

[image]

Here is the solution:

[image]

However, consider the definition of a total order relation:

[image]

The solution didn't prove that the relation is a partial order relation. This is a mistake in the solution, right?

Comment: I wouldn't call it a mistake. One could say it is incomplete, but it is likely that by the time this problem comes up, the reader has enough familiarity with the concepts to immediately identify that it is a partial order too.

Comment: Are you insisting on the "either - or" here? I.e. do you consider "$\le$" or do you consider "$<$" an order relation? Or do you complain because the proof in this form would also erroneously "show" that "divides" is a total order on $\{-2^n,-2^{n-1},\ldots,-4,-2-1,1,2,4,\ldots,2^n\}$?

Answer (score 1):

"Consider the "divides" relation..."

It is assumed that you are aware that divisibility is a partial order relation...